# Why is my integer increasing by multiples of 4?

Tags: xcode, nsuinteger

I have an if statement like this

```
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger *theScore;


if (hint.hidden) {
    theScore += (2);
        } else {
            theScore += (1);
                }
NSLog(@"Score changed");
score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", theScore];
```

But instead of theScore increasing by 2 or 1 it's increasing by 8 or 4

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's a pointer to the integer, not the integer itself. The 4 is the SIZE of the integer.

Change it to NSUInteger theScore, without the *.